# Is it possible for a button to trigger a form action and have the button trigger a jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have form which when submitted triggers a php script, however the submit button does not work if it trigger's a jquery function. Is it possible for the button to trigger a jquery function and a php script?

Here is my code:

```
<form action="./asset/php/savesettings.php" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <P class="noticeme">Please note that all of your settings are stored via cookies</P>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox">Disable page visit alert on page load</label>
        </div>  
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="text-centered">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success onclickspin" id="MSSave">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery function:

```
$("#MSSave").click(function(){
    $("#MSSave").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
    $('#MSSave').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

So basically the form action will not happen when the button "MSSave" has a jquery function attached to it.

Comment: @Dagon If I was to remove the jquery, the above code works, however it does not work when the jquery function exists

Comment: You want the button to do the form action and the jq function?

Comment: @Dagon Well, when I remove the jquery function and I click the button, the form action happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the id of `form` to the form and add this to the bottom of the jQuery function:

```
$("#form").submit();
```

Comment: I said that before you did :D

Answer (score 0):

Is there a design reason why you don't have the jQuery function execute the submit function? If there is, then I would recommend using the jquery $().bind("change keyup" ...)  function to bind the jquery function to the key-up (when you release the mouse button) after clicking on the submit button.

Comment: There was not a reason, I just did not realise you could trigger a form with jquery. I appreciate your help thought.